# Append multiple AJAX responses into individual Cards using JQuery/ JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've hit a roadblock I just can't get past after 5+ hours of fiddling. Basically what I'm trying to do is take responses from my API (a recipe search tool) and stick each individual recipe into its own card, having 2 cards side by side all the way down the page. The responses include various info about the recipe to be placed dynamically into each card, but everything I've tried working off the Doc's has just broken my page completely.

My JS (edited to remove a couple chars from my API key, sorry but it's a trial):

```html
//On Index page this function takes search bar input and gives ten results for recipes
function createRecipe() {
    var mealName = $("#recipeInput").val().trim();
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.edamam.com/search?q=" + mealName + "&app_id=70e00e26&app_key=6c683b56a399b435d00ee3100c0ca",
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function(response) {
        for (i = 0; i < response.hits.length; i++) {
            var newDiv = $("#recipeReveal");
            newDiv.append("<div class='card col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-10' style=''>")
                .append("<div class='card-body'>")
                .append("<h5>" + response.hits[i].recipe.label + "</h5>")
                .append("<img class='card-img-top'src='" + response.hits[i].recipe.image + "' alt='Recipe Picture'></img>")
                .append("<p class='card-text'>Full recipe instructions can be found at: <a href='" + response.hits[i].recipe.url + "'>" + response.hits[i].recipe.url + "</a></p>")
                .append("</div>")
                .append("<ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>");
            for (j = 0; j < response.hits[i].recipe.ingredients.length; j++) {
                newDiv.append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + response.hits[i].recipe.ingredients[j].text + "</li>");
            }
            newDiv.append("</ul>")
                .append("<div class='card-body'>")
                .append("<button id='result" + (i + 1) + "' onclick='saveRecipe(" + (i) + ")'>Save Recipe</button>")
                .append("</div></div>");
        }
        queriedRecipe0 = (response.hits[0].recipe.uri);
        queriedRecipe1 = (response.hits[1].recipe.uri);
        queriedRecipe2 = (response.hits[2].recipe.uri);
        queriedRecipe3 = (response.hits[3].recipe.uri);
        queriedRecipe4 = (response.hits[4].recipe.uri);
        queriedRecipe5 = (response.hits[5].recipe.uri);
        queriedRecipe6 = (response.hits[6].recipe.uri);
        queriedRecipe7 = (response.hits[7].recipe.uri);
        queriedRecipe8 = (response.hits[8].recipe.uri);
        queriedRecipe9 = (response.hits[9].recipe.uri);
    })
}
```

This is posting into a div with the appropriate ID "recipeReveal", i thought I had it working but it turns out I just made one really long container with a tiny little card at the top that you can't even see. The ideal situation would be to have each recipe in its own card, along with img response, URL, ingredient list, button, etc. If I can get them into individual cards I definitely think I can knock out the CSS/ Grid system aspects easily. Just the JQuery that's getting me.

PS - Any resources/ easy to understand documentation on this subject is also appreciated if you don't have the time to really dive into this one! Thank you. `

Comment: Your issue is related to you thinking `append()` adds html.  It does not.  When you `append('<div>')` is creates a div element.  If you later `append('</div>')` it will create yet another div.  There is no relation between multiple calls to `append()` remembering what you appended before.  Again, it's creating elements, not appending html

Comment: Either append one big template literal at a single time, or append all your html to a variable, and then at the end, append that variable to the dom.

Comment: @Taplar okay, so I'm essentially creating a ton of small elements that have literally nothing to do with one another here? (just wanna be sure I get it, I'm still a bit green).

Would I possibly be able to turn those individual appends into just one really long one with all of the responses in there as well as the bootstrap classes then? It would look a bit spaghetti, but from what you've just said that's the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Essentially anything that looks like `.append('<tag>').append('...stuff...').append('</tag>')` should be `append('<tag>...stuff...</tag>')` so the html is parsed with the correct nesting.  In the first form, yes, the logic would create two empty `tag` elements and some stray text some where in the middle

Comment: Okay, I really appreciate your quick reply here! I think I know what I have to do, with this many items it's going to look like Frankenstein's Monster when I'm done though. 

Whittle it down to one append with all of my desired HTML elements and classes inside.

Comment: @Taplar - follow up question, sorry for any inconvenience. That for loop that I have in there is giving me troubles. It's basically for generating a recipe list using results from the API, I assume I have to move it outside of the append, but how would I do so and still allow it to populate recipe specific ingredients for each of the 10 that populate?